# JavaFX getText from textfield when button pressed(FX Builder)

Tags: javafx

Currently in the process of learning myself JavaFX.

I have used Scene Builder to create a simple Scene with a button, and a textfield.

How come I can not click the button, and get the text from the textfield?

```
@FXML
private void handleButton1Action(ActionEvent event) {

    System.out.println(tittel.getText());


}
```

The FXML code is :

```
  <TextField id="tittel" fx:id="tittel" layoutX="120.0" layoutY="64.0" promptText="Tittel" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either add the action handler in the scene builder or add this to the FXML:

```
onAction="#handleButton1Action"
```

So in all:

```
<TextField id="tittel" fx:id="tittel" layoutX="120.0" layoutY="64.0" onAction="#handleButton1Action" promptText="Tittel" />
```

Comment: That action handler is already taken on the button, but that maybe has nothing to say? Still get an error though.

Comment: What does the error say? Perhaps post a the a *little* bit of the stack trace?

Comment: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Have you set the controller for the FXML document?

Comment: Yes, the whole application runs and works. But as soon as I use add the "getText", it crashes.

Comment: And have you done in the controller:
`@FXML TextField tittel;`

Comment: The `@FXML` tag is important

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54613/discussion-between-miniheessel-and-cobbles).

Comment: The problem was that I did not know that I needed a FXML tag for each.

Answer (score 7):

Add this line to your FXML code  `onAction="#handleButton1Action"`

like

`<TextField id="tittel" fx:id="tittel" onAction="#handleButton1Action" layoutX="120.0" layoutY="64.0" promptText="Tittel" />`

and add this line after your controller class declaration

```
@FXML private TextField tittel;
```

then add the action handler

```
@FXML
private void handleButton1Action(ActionEvent event) {

    System.out.println(tittel.getText());


}
```